# developing our own toolkit for .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am impressed by the toolkits like infragistics,telerik etc .

I was looking for the things i need to learn to develope my own toolkit.I have no clue from where to start.So please kindly help me by suggesting your valuable views or examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development of **Custom AJAX Control Toolkit Control Extender** ?
This [Creating a Custom AJAX Control Toolkit Control Extender](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/getting-started/creating-a-custom-ajax-control-toolkit-control-extender-cs) link may help you !
And you can reference this [ASP-NET-AJAX-Controls-and-Extenders CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22384/ASP-NET-AJAX-Controls-and-Extenders) link!

Comment: Oh , my bad , sorry @AlexeiLevenkov , `Ajax Extenders` ? isn't it ?

Comment: thanx for the help but i need the same thing for web applications

Comment: thanx a lot :),this gave me a good start...will ask further if required